# Installation of MudBlazor in a Blazor winforms application

Tags: winforms, blazor, builder, mudblazor

I was going through the installation for MudBlazor and I am having some issues with the following lines of code in the installation guide...

```
using MudBlazor.Services;

builder.Services.AddMudServices();
```

winforms does not contain a builder by default so I altered the program.cs file as figured below...

```
internal static class Program
{
    public static IServiceProvider? ServiceProvider { get; set; }
    static void ConfigureServices()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddMudServices();

        ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///  The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
        // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        ConfigureServices();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I can't figure out how to get started on combining the Windows Forms Blazor Hybrid with MudBlazor.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have MudBlazor setup correctly, by following the Blazor Winforms tutorial on [Microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/windows-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0), it looks like this can be done in the Form's constructor like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.WindowsForms;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MudBlazor.Services;

namespace YourNamespace;
public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddWindowsFormsBlazorWebView();
        services.AddMudServices();
        blazorWebView1.HostPage = "wwwroot\\index.html";
        blazorWebView1.Services = services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```